# calling malloc multiple times - higher than expected memory usage

Tags: c, memory-management

When I run the following 32 bit application (debug mode) under windows a memory usage reaches 2GB limit and loop breaks when i equals **42885988**:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 104857600; ++i)
{
    uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)malloc(1);

    if (!ptr)
    {
        break;
    }

    *ptr = 0;   
}
```

104857600 that's 100mb so how to explain a behavior of the above program ?

Comment: Keeping track of a block of memory isn’t free. Each allocation is going to use more than one byte.

Comment: @Ry- Could you please explain it in more details ?

Comment: I don’t know the details for Windows. Seems like the “Low Fragmentation Heap” is a thing. At the very least, though, you have 8-byte alignment.

Comment: You are aware that allocating one single byte of memory is really pointless anyway.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - There is nothing wrong with an academic question once in a while.  Especially when all of the practical questions for `C` seem to have been asked and answered. :)

Comment: @ryyker don't misunderstand me, the question is OK. I just wanted to make sure that the OP understands this.

Comment: @Jabberwocky allocating one single byte... but if an algorithm allocates just the needed memory, and you feed it with little data? Like a text editor opening a long file filled with 1-char lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`malloc(1)` doesn't allocate one byte.

The `malloc` man page notes that the memory returned "is suitably aligned for any built-in type." So if the first call to `malloc` returns address 0x1000, the second call probably can't return 0x1001, because that address might not be "suitably aligned for any built-in type." (Some processors can't access words at odd addresses, or generally N-byte values at addresses not evenly divisible by N, and some of those that can do so less efficiently.) So the second `malloc` call will have to return at least 0x1004 or even 0x1008.

Also, `malloc` has to allocate extra memory to store information about the buffer it returns to you. When you later call `free`, that function has to know the size of the buffer, for example. On a 64-bit machine that's at least another 8 bytes. Depending on how the runtime manages the heap, it may have to store additional information.

If you assume that each `malloc` actually allocates at least 8 bytes (for alignment) plus another 8 or 16 for housekeeping, you can see that 100 million calls to `malloc` of one byte each can get you over 2GB.

I'm not sure if each of your calls is actually using 16 or 24 bytes or whatever; the point is that it's a lot more than one.

Answer (score 4):

2GB/42885988 is a shade over 50 bytes per allocation.

This is more that would be expected from a simple Windows heap allocation, so I suspect you are running a DEBUG build, in which case there is extra overhead of guard bytes around your allocated memory. More details can be found in this article - http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html .

Comment: Yes. I run the application in the debug mode.